# Opencart, removing vat on postage and packing

Tags: php, opencart

Wonder if anyone can help.

I understand this is possibly more an opencart configuration question, so apologies if I have posted in a wrong area - but I'm wondering if this is something that I will need to code in.

My client want's me to have postage & packing cost not included in the subtotal (eg not subject to vat) and added on after - as apparently postage and packing are not taxed in the UK.

Anyone got any pointers on how I can achieve this ? I can't see any options in opencart itself to cater for this.

Thanks For looking

MRO

Answer (score 0):

The postage option should have a tax class setting. Just set that to none

Answer (score 0):

Your client is wrong, P&P is fully VATable in the UK...unless you're selling 0% VAT goods like books.